# Is there a way to use a BETWEEN clause to get total of sold games for date ranges (using or not using a CASE statement) in a single query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, case, between

I've tried the code below but it throws an error:

```
SELECT Publisher, SUM(Global_Sales) AS total_games_sold, Year,
CASE 
WHEN Year < 1989 THEN SUM(Global_Sales)
WHEN Year BETWEEN 1990 AND 1999 THEN SUM(Global_Sales)
WHEN Year BETWEEN 2000 AND 2009 THEN SUM(Global_Sales)
ELSE Year > 2009 END AS Dates
FROM Vgsales
ORDER BY Year;
```

Comment: `CASE WHEN Year < 1989 THEN '< 1989' WHEN ... END AS YearRange`, then `GROUP BY YearRange`. It's not the `SUM` that's varying here.

Comment: Imagine you had a small table that contains the date ranges you were interested in. You could then join to that table and compute the values you desire. This is a minor variation of a calendar table - a "tool" that someone doing analysis should both have and know how to use. And for future reference, post any error you encounter - "throws an error" is not useful information generally.

Comment: @DataAnalystTableau Can you please share expected output with dummy values?

Comment: Yh sure, so the 'Result' shown by Zhorov in the answer below shows exactly the result I'm looking for

Answer (score 6):

If I understand your issue correctly, you need to use `SUM` with conditions:

Data:

```
SELECT *
INTO Vgsales
FROM (VALUES
   ('Publisher One', 1000, 1988),
   ('Publisher One', 2000, 1990),
   ('Publisher One', 3000, 1991),
   ('Publisher One', 4000, 2001),
   ('Publisher One', 5000, 2010)
) v (Publisher, Global_Sales, [Year])
```

Statement:

```
SELECT 
   Publisher, 
   SUM(Global_Sales) AS [total_games_sold], 
   SUM(CASE WHEN Year < 1989 THEN Global_Sales END) AS [1989_games_sold],
   SUM(CASE WHEN Year BETWEEN 1990 AND 1999 THEN Global_Sales END) AS [1990_1999_games_sold],
   SUM(CASE WHEN Year BETWEEN 2000 AND 2009 THEN Global_Sales END) AS [2000_2009_games_sold],
   SUM(CASE WHEN Year > 2009 THEN Global_Sales END) AS [2009_games_sold]
FROM Vgsales
GROUP BY Publisher
ORDER BY Publisher
```

Result:

| Publisher | total_games_sold | 1989_games_sold | 1990_1999_games_sold | 2000_2009_games_sold | 2009_games_sold |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Publisher One | 15000 | 1000 | 5000 | 4000 | 5000 |

Comment: Thank you, yes this is result is exactly what I was looking for. However, when I run the code I get this error:

Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[total_games_sold],     SUM(CASE WHEN Year < 1989 THEN Global_Sales END) AS [198' at line 3

Comment: Oh sorry, my bad, I am using MySQL, not Microsoft SQL server, that might be why as I know MySQL syntax differs.

Comment: Thanks but I've tried that (removing the square brackets) and still get the same error, in both MySQL and in Microsoft SQL server

Comment: I noticed that your 'Year' data type is an 'INT', on my data it is a 'YEAR', maybe this is the issue why it isn't working for me

Comment: *"on my data it is a 'YEAR'"* How is that different than an integer?

Answer (score -1):

#### APPROACH 1 :

If you need result in multiple columns, you can try joining multiple result sets.

```
SELECT a.Publisher,total_games_sold,b.total AS '<1989', c.total AS '1990-1999',d.total AS '2000-2009', e.total AS '>2009'
FROM
(
SELECT Publisher, SUM(Global_Sales) AS total_games_sold
FROM Vgsales
GROUP BY Publisher
) a

FULL OUTER JOIN
(
SELECT Publisher, SUM(Global_Sales) AS total
FROM Vgsales
WHERE YEAR < 1989 
GROUP BY Publisher
) b ON a.Publisher = b.Publisher

FULL OUTER JOIN
(
SELECT Publisher, SUM(Global_Sales) AS total
FROM Vgsales
WHERE YEAR BETWEEN 1990 AND 1999 
GROUP BY Publisher
) c ON a.Publisher = c.Publisher

FULL OUTER JOIN
(
SELECT Publisher, SUM(Global_Sales) AS total
FROM Vgsales
WHERE YEAR BETWEEN 2000 AND 2009
GROUP BY Publisher
) d ON a.Publisher = d.Publisher

FULL OUTER JOIN
(
SELECT Publisher, SUM(Global_Sales) AS total
FROM Vgsales
WHERE YEAR >2009
GROUP BY Publisher
) e ON a.Publisher = e.Publisher
```

*Output:*

| Publisher | total_games_sold | <1989 | 1990-1999 | 2000-2009 | >2009 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| pub1 | 10 | 5 | 2 | 2 | 1 |
| pub2 | 20 | 15 | 1 | 2 | 2 |
| pub3 | 40 | 5 | 25 | 5 | 5 |
| pub4 | 5 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 1 |

#### APPROACH 2:

If you need result in multiple rows, you can try doing UNION.

```
SELECT Publisher, SUM(Global_Sales) AS total_games_sold, '<1989' AS Year
FROM Vgsales
WHERE YEAR < 1989 
GROUP BY Publisher

UNION ALL

SELECT Publisher, SUM(Global_Sales) AS total_games_sold, '1990-1999' AS Year
FROM Vgsales
WHERE YEAR BETWEEN 1990 AND 1999
GROUP BY Publisher

UNION ALL

SELECT Publisher, SUM(Global_Sales) AS total_games_sold, '2000-2009' AS Year
FROM Vgsales
WHERE YEAR BETWEEN 2000 AND 2009
GROUP BY Publisher

UNION ALL

SELECT Publisher, SUM(Global_Sales) AS total_games_sold, '>2009' AS Year
FROM Vgsales
WHERE Year > 2009
GROUP BY Publisher;
```

*Output:*

| Publisher | total_games_sold | Year |
| --- | --- | --- |
| pub1 | 33332 | <1989 |
| pub1 | 13233 | 1990-1999 |
| pub1 | 753233 | 2000-2009 |
| pub1 | 4037221 | >2009 |